# How can I use split() operator when I try sort list of tuples?

Tags: python

I have some list of tuples:

```
a = [('3 232', 'm3', 'some_value'), ('1', 'm', 'some_value'), ('90', 'cm3', 'some_value')]
```

I try sort it by first element in every tuple:

```
sorted(a, key=lambda x: int(x.strip()[0]))
```

But i have AttributeError:

> AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'strip'

Why it so and how i can delete spaces in every first tuples element?

I will be grateful for the help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You meant `x[0].strip()`, not `x.strip()[0]`, but even that won't do what you expect.

`strip` removes characters from the start and end of a string. You should use `replace`:

```
x[0].replace(' ', '')
```

As a whole:

```
sorted(a, key=lambda x: int(x[0].replace(' ', ''))
```

Comment: @MrOldSir click the checkmark next to their answer if this solves your question.